# Drupal 6 views_embed_view ignores content filtering?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

may be someone encountered a similar issue. I output a view on the front page of my D6 site using this code:

```
<?php print views_embed_view("frontpage_news_list", "default" ); ?>
```

Yet it seems that this way of outputting the view bypasses content filtering for the teaser field (NOT the view filter, but filters applied to the teaser of the node). I see this because I don't output img's in my teasers, and they are not shown when I check preview in the Views UI, yet on the front page the images are shown in this view.

I have another view, with outputs the nodes of the same type in a "Page" output, and the img's are hidden in the teasers there, as required.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before? I would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem with the HTMLawed module, not with the Views. It has been solved by the developer now, so no issue anymore. Thanks for the help, guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
  // you can use block_1, ... blocn_n or page_1,...,page_n as display id
  print views_embed_view("frontpage_news_list", "block_1" ); 

  // or this way to show view
  $view = views_get_viev(YOU_VIEW_MACHINE_NAME);
  $view->set_display($display_id);
  // $view->set_exposed_input(array('var' => $myvar)); // to set exposed filters
  // $view->set_arguments(array(....)); // to set arguments. rtfm ;)
  $view->set_items_per_page(0);
  $view->execute();
  $result = $view->preview();
  print $result;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback, though this did not depend on output method for me, for some reason.